# Phonegap iOS Error : the password for the associated certificate is incorrect

Tags: ios, cordova, authentication, certificate, phonegap

I'm having a problem with phonegap-build. When I'm building my application for IOS system gives error:

> Error - the password for the associated certificate is incorrect - You can fix this [here](https://build.phonegap.com/people/edit)

Interesting part is this is happening on a key that **I was already using** for the same application.

1.0.0 - 1.0.1 - 1.0.2 - 1.0.3 it was OK, I successfully uploaded my applications to **iTunes** before.

Here is my background: This is my application on github:
[https://github.com/turtlepile/AvrasyaTurk](http://Application)

And this is my last checkin, last fix I did on my config. I added few lines to add img sources for my splash screen for iOS.

[https://github.com/turtlepile/AvrasyaTurk/blob/master/config.xml](http://Config%20Checkin)

I checked, and did not find any expired certificates in my key-chain (mac)

My application ID: **2827097**

EDIT: I'm 99% sure that my "unlock" pass-word is correct, but is there anywhere where i can confirm this? I'm not well-informed with ios/mac/apple products so i'm not sure is there a way to do this on the macbook that I creted my .p12 file.

EDIT2: I tried some "it worked" ideas I saw on forums:

- locked all keys, and unlocked them again on sign-certificates page -> didn't work
- locked all key.s -> get lates/rebuild -> get "locked error" -> unlock & rebuild again -> didn't work
- checked key-chains for expired certificates.
- tried to add the same key to my adobe account with different name, 
  added key (AppStore_v2) -> unlock it -> used that key,  -> didn't work

I posted my problem on AdobeForums as well but no-one replied yet.

Comment: Nobody answered and i had a deadline issue, so here how i solved: I created another .p12 certificate on my Mac, and set up a new password (no special chars in in) and add new key to phonegap, and problem solved.. was able to build my ipa again. Problem is, it's frustrating because i was 99% sure about info i was putting in, if this happens again i will NOT try to look for more, and create another cert and continue.. i suggest you to do the same because with IOS, everything is harder than it supposed to be..!

Comment: I am actually going through the exact same problem! This is the third time updating my iOS app, but all of a sudden Phonegap wont accept the password. I guess I better just create another certificate like you did.

Comment: hello there :) yes, unfortunately that's the only way